# Notification for Config Variables changes on heroku

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

is there a way to setup Heroku to get a notification you when your config variables are updated?

thanks a lot

sorry for the very late reply, but I spoke with Heroku back then, and they said that it wasn't something that they did at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Very late to the party here, but just to give an updated answer. Heroku has support for webhooks so you can monitor those + more events on your end.

If you rather not build your own consumption pipeline, consider using [LightFlare](https://lightflare.bytebeacon.com) (I'm the creator) that has out of the box support of consuming Webhooks events from many services (heroku included) and notifies you at your choice(s) of destinations (slack / email etc ...).

[LightFlare](https://lightflare.bytebeacon.com) currently supports monitoring on services like:

- Infra: GCP, AWS, Azure, heroku
- Code/release: GitHub, bitbucket, netlify
- Commerce: shopify, gumroad
- More integrations based on our customers asks